# PROBLEMA PARA RECORRER REGISTROS EN PYTHON

Tags: python, base-de-datos, tkinter, sqlite

tengo una clase(Busquedas) con la que quiero realizar búsquedas sobre una base de datos al apretar un botón en una interfaz de tkinter, el problema es que una vez creado el obj en la función(mostrarSiguiente) desde la cual la voy a llamar, la primera vez me muestra el registro correcto(al entrar en el else-->print(busq.view_row(busq.select_row_next()))), pero en la primer opción del condicional al cual entra siempre la segunda vez que se llama a esta función me sale None... alguna idea de que esta mal?

'''

```
class Busquedas:
    def __init__(self, tabla):
        self._base = Base()
        self._cursor = self._base.conexion.cursor()
        self._tabla = tabla
        self._index = 0

    def select_row_next(self):
        return self._cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM {self._tabla}')

    def select_row_next2(self):
        return self._cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM {self._tabla} WHERE id={self._index+1}')
    
    def select_row_preview(self):
        return self._cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM {self._tabla} WHERE id={self._index-1}')
    
    def view_row(self, func):
        register = self._cursor.fetchone()
        if register is not None:
            self._index = register[0]
            return register


# función en la que se instancia la clase y se llama a sus métodos(esta esta pertenece a otra clase)
            
def mostrarSiguiente(self, tabla):
        busq = con.Busquedas(tabla)
        self.acu = self.acu + 1
        if self.acu > 1:
            print(busq.view_row(busq.select_row_next2()))
        else:
            print(busq.view_row(busq.select_row_next()))
```

'''

Comment: En view_row en lugar de usar ```self._cursor.fetchone()``` Debería ser ```func.fetchone```

Comment: hola muchas gracias, voy a probarlo, saludos

Comment: acabo de probarlo pero sigue haciendo lo mismo, voy a seguir intentando a ver que sucede o tratar de ver otra osibilidad

Comment: El problema que detecto es que la variable self._index = 0 al estar en __init__ es la que crea el problema ya que siempre se inicializa a cero.

Comment: Así es, siempre creas el objeto en ```mostrarSigiiente```, self.acu también se inicializa. Me pareció que ```mostrarSiguiente``` pertenecía a la clase ```Busquedas``` y supuse que la identacion era un problema de copy/paste. Sin embargo es un método de otra clase. Entonces, no crees el objeto ```Busquedas``` en este metodo sino en el ```init``` de la clase a la cual pertenece.

Comment: hola que tal lo solucione declarando a index como variable de clase fuera de __init__, al comienzo de la clase... saludos